# ProcessPoolExecutor Error, Int is not iterable/subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn how python handles multiprocessing and have followed a youtube tutorial for some basic code but I am now trying to implement a ProcessPoolExecuter myself.

I have the following code which is causing the problem:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(func, sets, repeat(testNumbers))

        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

where the function func takes set which is a list of sets and listOfGames (Which I want to be passed every time, I think I have done this correctly using repeat, this is a 2d list of integers) and returns a dictionary.

When I run this code I get the error: int object is not iterable which comes from the printing stage in the code.

Is there another way I should be getting the results?

This is a small piece of the code which reproduces the bug

```
import itertools
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import repeat

def singleGameWinner(game, playedNumbers):
    if(set(playedNumbers).issubset(set(game))):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def getPowerSet(listOfNumbers, length):
    powerset = itertools.combinations(listOfNumbers, length)
    return list(set(powerset))

def sortDict(unsorted):
    sortedDict = sorted(unsorted, key = lambda i: i['Games Ago'], reverse=True)
    return sortedDict

def getWinners(games, sets):
    results=[]
    for i in range(len(sets)):
        count = 0
        gamesAgo = -1
        for j in reversed(range(len(games))):
            if(singleGameWinner(games[j], sets[i])):
                count += 1
                drawNumber = games[j][1]
                gamesAgo = games[j][0]
                # gamesAgo = finalDataNumber-gamesAgo
        results.append({
            "Set": sets[i],
            "Wins": int(count),
            "Games Ago": int(gamesAgo),
            "Draw Number": int(drawNumber)
        })
    return sortDict(results)

def getRecentWinners(sets, games):
    finalDataNumber = games[-1][0]
    results = []
    for i in range(len(sets)):
        count = len(games)
        gamesAgo = -1
        foundGame = False
        while(not foundGame and count > 0):
            count -= 1
            if(singleGameWinner(games[count], sets[i])):
                foundGame = True
                gamesAgo = games[count][0]
                drawNumber = games[count][1]
                gamesAgo = finalDataNumber-gamesAgo
                results.append({
                    "Set": sets[i],
                    "Games Ago": int(gamesAgo),
                    "Draw Number": int(drawNumber)
                })
    return sortDict(results)

def main():
    listOfGames = [x for x in range(1,22)]
    testNumbers = [1,2]
    sets = getPowerSet(testNumbers, 2)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(getRecentWinners, sets, repeat(listOfGames))
        for result in results:
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual value being passed as the second argument *games* to `getRecentWinners` is `listOfGames`, which as a values of `[1, 2, 3 ... 21]`. But the first line of `getRecentWinners` is:

```py
def getRecentWinners(sets, games):
    finalDataNumber = games[-1][0] # this is the line throwing the exception
```

But the stacktrace reveals this if you look carefully:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 239, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 198, in _process_chunk
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 198, in <listcomp>
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 39, in getRecentWinners
    finalDataNumber = games[-1][0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 65, in main
    for result in results:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

But to answer your question "Is there another way I should be getting the results?", it is not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish. Clearly treating an integer (21 in this case) as if it were something that were subscriptable makes no sense. So did you mean to pass something else or did you mean to not be subscripting this? Moreover, you have the following code:

```py
def getPowerSet(listOfNumbers, length):
    powerset = itertools.combinations(listOfNumbers, length)
    return list(set(powerset))
```

You call this function with the *listOfNumbers* argument specified as `[1, 2]` and *length* specified as `2`, which is the length of the list. Will the second argument always be the length of the first argument? If so, this then if we step through the calculations performed by this function, we have:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> listOfNumbers = [1, 2]
>>> length = 2
>>> powerset = itertools.combinations(listOfNumbers, length)
>>> s = set(powerset)
>>> s
{(1, 2)}
>>> list(s)
[(1, 2)]
```

When you call the `combinations` function against a list of numbers and pass as the second argument the length of that list, there is only one way you can  take N elements N at a time. So all that you end up with is a tuple of the original list of numbers. Then when you pass that tuple as an argument to the `set` constructor, you end up with a set with a single element, namely the tuple. Finally, you then construct a list passing as the *iterable* the set, so all you have succeeded is creating is a list with the single tuple. That entire function could have been re-coded as:

```py
def getPowerSet(listOfNumbers):
    return [tuple(listOfNumbers)]
```

That couldn't have been what you had in mind.

Even if the second argument will not be the length of the first argument (presumably a smaller value), `combinations` will yield unique tuples. So what is the point of first creating a set from these values before creating a list? That would only make sense if you needed to remove duplicate values first.

**Another Way Avoiding repeat**

You could make *games* the *first* argument to `getRecentWinners`:

```py
from functools import partial

def getRecentWinners(games, sets):
    ... # etc.
```

And then invoke `map` as follows:

```py
def main():
    listOfGames = [x for x in range(1,22)]
    testNumbers = [1,2]
    sets = getPowerSet(testNumbers, 2)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(partial(getRecentWinners, listOfGames), sets)
    ... # etc.
```

**Update**

So now to get rid of the original Exception, you are making `listOfGames` a list of lists, for example:

```py
    listOfGames = [[x for x in range(1,22)]]
```

(But you really should now be updating your question with the updated source and including and the new stacktrace), which is:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 239, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 198, in _process_chunk
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 198, in <listcomp>
    return [fn(*args) for args in chunk]
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 47, in getRecentWinners
    if(singleGameWinner(games[count], sets[i])):
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 6, in singleGameWinner
    if(set(playedNumbers).issubset(set(game))):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Ron\test\test.py", line 65, in main
    for result in results:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
    for element in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So line 6 is throwing the excpetion:

```py
def singleGameWinner(game, playedNumbers):
    if(set(playedNumbers).issubset(set(game))): # this line is the problem
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So we insert a new first line to this function to print out the input arguments se we see what is going on:

```py
def singleGameWinner(game, playedNumbers):
    print('game =', game, 'playedNumbers =', playedNumbers)
    if(set(playedNumbers).issubset(set(game))):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And this prints:

```
game = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21] playedNumbers = 1
```

So the problem is the expression `set(playedNumbers)` becuase the `set` constructor requires an *iterable* such as a `list` and here you are passing a single `int`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, to answer your questions. listOfGames is meant to be a list of lists holding integers (Representing keno games if you're familiar) and im trying to. For `getPowerSet` the length of `listOfNumbers` will vary as will length. Overall im just trying to run multiple processes of `getRecentWinners` to speed up computation for large sets of `listOfGames` and also `sets`.

Comment: Did my answer clarify anything for you as to your problem? And yes, `length`, the second argument to  `getPowerSet` will vary but if it's always varying such that it is the length of the first argument, it make no sense. And there is no reason for `return list(set(powerset))`; it should be `return list(powerset)`.

Comment: Yes, your answer did clarify some things however after changing `listOfGames` to a list of lists the error is now `int is not iterable`. After reading the stacktrace it highlights `if(singleGameWinner(games[count], sets[i])):` and `if(set(playedNumbers).issubset(set(game))):` which has no iteration. To reproduce this bug you just need to make `listOfGames` a list of lists.

Comment: See my updated answer. This is basic debugging: You need to look at the stacktrace to determine where in your source you are getting the error and then insert print statements to look at values if necessary.